# Showing Application Error in Zend Web Development on server

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework

I am new to Zend framework. I developed an application and its working perfectly working on localhost and on freestlye servers , but on other server its showing some thing like this

```
An Error Occurred
Application Error
```

I tried all feasible changes in .htaccess file but it couldn't work.
here is content of my .htaccess file

```
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
    RewriteEngine On
    # The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
    # exists, simply serve it.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    # The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
    # condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
    # mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
    # allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
    # in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
    # fits all solution.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]

    # PHP settings
    #php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
    #php_flag register_globals off
    #php_flag short_open_tag on
```

Kindly help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Add your credentials under Production in application.ini file and let me know it works or not